# compare two values and generate a percentage (excel)

Tags: excel, percentage, vba

I am currently trying to create a spreadsheet which keeps track of how many files have been quality checked against those that haven't and then displays the amount left to be checked as a percentage.

Currently on open the spreadsheet pulls the details from a checked folder and a work to be checked folder as follows:-

```
Private Sub pdf_loading()

Range("M5").Clear

Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
FolderPath = "C:\path to folder\"
' looks in spercific folder
path = FolderPath & "*.pdf"
' for file type this time it is pdf files, though if you change this is could be word files, or psd's
Filename = Dir(path)

Do While Filename <> ""
' checks for filename <less than or >greater than "filename" as "" is empty does not look for spercific file
    count = count + 1
' counts amount of pdf files, add 1 to the last known number
    Filename = Dir()
' contiunes count until it reaches the end of the directory
Loop


Range("M5").Value = count
' puts final count value in cell

For Each Cell In [M:M]
If Cell.Value = "0" Then
Cell.ClearContents
ElseIf Range("M5").Value >= 1 Then
End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Then for the checked folder:-

```
Private Sub checked_loading()

Range("M6").Clear

Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
FolderPath = "C:\path to folder\"

path = FolderPath & "*.pdf"

Filename = Dir(path)

Do While Filename <> ""
    count = count + 1
        Filename = Dir()
Loop

Range("M6").Value = count

For Each Cell In [M:M]
If Cell.Value = "0" Then
Cell.ClearContents
ElseIf Range("M5").Value >= 1 Then
End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

This works fine, though currently the formula I have tried to generate the percentage is as follows:-

```
=IF(M5=M6,"50%",IF(M5=0,"100%",IF(M6=0,"0%",SUM(M5*M6/100*1))))
```

This brings back incorrect results like 144.00% when the files to be check result is 9 and the files checked result is 16.

I would prefer to have the percentage calculation to be in vba so that end users could not accidentally delete the underlying formula.

Any help on this issue or if there is a more efficient code structure would be most appreciate.

Comment: Thank you @pnuts though this does not always give a correct answer, I have however corrected my coding so that the two values are totaled and then a percentage equation can be derived from that.

Answer (score 0):

Not to worry I have found a solution which works a treat. The above code now looks like this for the work to be checked:-

```
Private Sub pdf_loading()

Range("K5:L6").ClearContents
Range("M5").ClearContents
' Clear cell contents on open

Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
FolderPath = "C:\filepath\folder\"
' looks in spercific folder
path = FolderPath & "*.pdf"
' for file type this time it is pdf files, though if you change this is could be word files, or psd's
Filename = Dir(path)

Do While Filename <> ""
' checks for filename <less than or >greater than "filename" as "" is empty does not look for spercific file
    count = count + 1
' counts amount of pdf files, add 1 to the last known number
    Filename = Dir()
' contiunes count until it reaches the end of the directory
Loop


Range("M5").Value = count
' puts final count value in cell




End Sub
```

and the work checked folder is now like this:-

```
Private Sub checked_loading()

Range("M6").ClearContents

Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
FolderPath = "C:\filepath\folder\"

path = FolderPath & "*.pdf"

Filename = Dir(path)

Do While Filename <> ""
    count = count + 1
        Filename = Dir()
Loop

Range("M6").Value = count


Range("N5").Formula = "=Sum(M5,M6)"
Range("K5").Formula = "=SUM(M6/N5*1)"
' adds formulas to selected cells to give percentage
End Sub
```